# java.io.ioexception permission denied android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to get frames from video via using ffmpeg command in android 
ffmcommand for the same is :

```
String[] ffmpegCommand = {
                    "ffmpeg",
                    "-1",
                    "-y ",
                    "-vcodec",
                    "mjpeg",
                    "-vframes",
                    "1",
                    "-an",
                    "-f",
                    "rawvideo",
                    "-s",
                    "320X240",
                    "-i",
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                            + "/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/video.mp4",
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                        + "/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/frame_%05d.jpg"};
```

In My manifest i have already given:

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

But still i am getting error of:

```
java.io.ioexception permission denied android
```

Please advice me on this or with some other `ffmpeg` command

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is important where you put that permission (what is the parent node). Also, please post the `adb logcat` log, probably it will tell us more.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your path: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24538917/4224337

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?